# Probability measure on a Polish space that has full-support and vanishes on the boundaries?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a Polish space, endowed with Borel sigma-algebra. Does there always exist a probability measure $\mu$ over $X$ such that (i) $\mu$ assigns a positive probability for each open subset of $X$, and (ii) for every Borel subset $A\subseteq X$, $\mu(\partial A)=0$ where $\partial A$ is the boundary of $A$?

If $X$ is a Euclid space, we can take a multi-variate normal distribution, for example. So if $X$ is homeomorphic to a Euclid space, I think we are done. But for more general Polish spaces?

Thank you very much in advance!
Best.

Comment: I see. I wanted to know whether a sort of ''continuous'' distributions like normal is possible in general, but I admit that my notion of ''continuity'' based on the boundary condition does not make sense, even for a normal distribution. Thank you guys, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

For $X =\Bbb{R}^n$, this is already impossible because of $\partial \Bbb{Q}^n =\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Even changing the condition to "the boundary of an open set must have measure zero" will not do.  There are open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ with boundary of positive Lebesgue measure (and therefore positive measure for the standard Gaussian measure).

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes. By regularity of Lebesgue (or gaussian) measure, we can even find an open set $U \supset \Bbb{Q}^n$ with $m(U)<\epsilon$ for arbitrary $\epsilon >0$. We then have $\partial U= \Bbb{R}^n \setminus U$, so that we can even make the (gaussian) measure of $\partial U$ as large as we like (but $<1$ of course).